# Fill a plane with circles in it

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, faces, edges

I am currently trying to make this wall with these roundles in it ]but when I try to fill the plane it fills the circles as well.
How to only fill the space between the circles and plane?
[image: photo1][image: photo2][image: photo3]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> instead of <kbd>F</kbd>, so that it can use triangles and fill properly the plane. After that use a <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* to remove as many inner edges as possible (you'll still have edges because you need edges that connect the inner edges with the outer edges, but you can connect other vertices if you want):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, but the easiest way for you doing this 100% in `EDIT MODE`  would be to use the `Intersect Boolean` tool.

Move your circles away from the plane
[image]

Select everything and fill them
[image]

Select only the circles and extrude them through the plane
[image]

Select all of the extruded circles
[image]

Then from the `Face` menu choose `Intersect Boolean`
[image]

This should be your result
[image]

This gives very bad geometry but as your learning you will learn how to make much better geometry as you go.

Hope this helps and Happy Blendering